# What do I do when I can't run a code as it appears syntax error near unexpected token `(' when I already complile it?

Tags: bash

I am trying to use a simple do while loop but I tried running it and  it appeared

```
$ ./credit.c
$ ./credit.c: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$ ./credit.c: line 4: `int main (void)'
```

This is my code

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main  (void)
{
    long number = get_long("Number: ");
    printf("%li\n",number);
}
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: First, bash isn't valid as this is C. Second, what compiler are you using?

Comment: This isn't a bash shell script, it's a C source code file.  The C language statements are very different from ones that shells understand, so you get the syntax error.  You have to compile C source code with a compiler.  See the example in https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/an_introduction_to_gcc/gccintro_9.html

Comment: Try adding `#! /usr/bin/tcc -run` as the first line (you'll likely need to install `tcc` a C compiler than can also execute the resulting command directly making it a C interpreter) to make it a C script.

Comment: *"when I already complile it"* so the compiled program goes to a different file, and that's the file you should run. Depending exactly **how** you compiled it, the file may be called something like `a.out`.